# How to make a method run on startup in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a method that draws the background of a picture box when I first open the application. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawBackground();

}

public void DrawBackground() 
        {
            Graphics SimWindow = pictureBoxSimDisplay.CreateGraphics();

            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

            SimWindow.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 211, 491,5);
        }
```

but its not working.

Comment: do you want to draw the background of the picturebox only at the beginning and not again?

Comment: i want to keep it there all the time

Comment: then in your OnLoad method you should write something like: pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("your_pic.jpg");

Comment: can i do the same if i want to draw it using a method?

Comment: yea, sure. but you should call that Method in OnLoad method.

Comment: How are you drawing it, to a `Bitmap` or using the `Graphics` object and drawing directly on the `PictureBox`? Showing your DrawBackground Method would probably help.

Comment: are you sure `DrawBackground();` works normally? meaning try taking a button and onclick call `DrawBackground();` ..does it work?

Comment: yep it dose i did that and it works fine

Answer (score 2):

I would personally override the Forms [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) Method, that way the background that you you draw on it will be redrawn when ever the Form is repainted including the initial load, If you are adding a image or a bitmap you should use the Form Load event as others have stated.

From above Link:

> The OnPaint method is overridden to repaint the image each time the
>   form is painted; otherwise the image would only persist until the next
>   repainting

.

---

Give this a try. I found that using the OnPaint Method is a little erratic on the initial load, but if I use a Timer(100ms) to Invalidate the Form it works fine every time.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    DrawBackground();

}

public void DrawBackground()
{
    Graphics SimWindow = pictureBoxSimDisplay.CreateGraphics();
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
    SimWindow.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 211, 491, 5);
    SimWindow.Dispose(); // Don't forget to dispose your Graphic Object
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in WinForms (?) is there any reason you cannot do that in the main form's OnLoad method?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you want to do something when the app runs?  If so then just do it all in your Main() / OnLoad().  If you are saying that you want to do it when the machine starts then throw some windows tags on this! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using forms you can double click on your form in the [Design] window and it will take you to your "Form1"_Load method where code runs when the form loads.